# cache with different url parameter

Tags: javascript, caching

I'm reading that a url is cached based on the file AND parameter. 
I have a html file with some javascript that processes parameters that are passed in. I want to cache the file but if the parameter changes, then it has to load the entire file each time which defeats having a cache. How do I cache the file when the parameter changes all the time?

Comment: When should you legitimately miss the cache when requesting that cached file? What sort of cache are you using? Are your parameters used for local routing (i.e. after a # in the url) or meant to be handled on the server?

Comment: Why would you send parameters to the server if you only process them clientside? Don't use a query string, use a fragment identifier instead (which still can be copy&pasted but won't get sent to the server or affect caching)

Comment: Thanks Bergi. Using "#" instead of "?" That works great! Didn't even think of it. I need to mark this as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Caching with a query string if a difficult process. Each node (web-browser, proxy server, net-caching engine) has it own distinct policy on how to deal with query string caching.

The best thing you can do is follow best practice, you should utilize the `Cache-Control`, `ETag`, `Expires` and `Last-Modified` headers if possible. There is a really good article [on this website](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2010/easy-cache-headers/) that goes into best practices.

In general that's your only real option to get nodes to cache content.